# Silverlight dynamic bulk file download application

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I'd like to create a Silverlight 4 (or 5) application that can bulk/batch download files from the hosting web server. On the client, the user will be presented with a list of files from which they select one or more of them to download. From that point, I'm trying to figure out how this will work. I would like to **avoid** prompting the user multiple times (e.g. once for each file). There should be just a single "save as" prompt, and from there, the download should execute.

Here are my initial thoughts:

**(1) Save File in Client**

If there was a way the user could select a "drop folder" where the files would be downloaded, writing them to disk might not be too difficult. However, I'm not aware of any way to do this in Silverlight. Isolated Storage was the first thing that popped into my mind, but it won't be easy for the user to get to that location once the files have been written... As far as I know, there's just the SaveFileDialog, and I certainly don't want to prompt the user for the location and name of each file.

**(2) Download File from Server**

If we could somehow utilize the browser's built in (save/open) download capabilities, this would be an easy option. I've found a few basic articles demonstrating how to do this, but I think our scenario becomes complicated because there are multiple files and the files that the user selects to download in a batch is dynamic. In my mind, I guess I'm thinking of creating some type of "on the fly" zip/archive containing the files the user selects to download and then downloading the zip as a single file.

Any thoughts or suggestions on how something like this could be implemented? I'm sure it's possible, but it's just new territory for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as you have done most of the research. Silverlight will have to prompt(SaveDialog) whenever you want to download any data to client machine, because silverlight applications run in a sandbox, means you can't access any local file and folder without a dialog prompt.

i think the solution fits best where you download the file in silverlight try to have them all in memory then use SharpZipLib for silverlight and try to compress the files on the fly.

http://liviutrifoi.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/silverlight-create-zip-file-with-folder/

Regards.

Comment: Perfect! SharpZipLib allowed me to create a single zip file on the fly containing the files the user specified. I converted the zip stream into a byte array for saving on the client. Thanks for the response.